# How can I reset my iPhone 1 without using the (broken) power button?

Tags: iphone

The power button on my first-gen iPhone is broken. I remember last time I came across this problem I found a utility (for windows) which caused the phone <s>to reset</s> to enter restore mode (the one with the yellow alert symbol), but I can't for the life of me find it again. Does anyone know what it is?

Thanks for any help,
Wyatt.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know about the yellow alert symbol, but a quick google for "iphone recovery mode utility" revealed [RecBoot](http://jaxov.com/2010/11/download-recboot-1-3-for-windows-mac-os-x-linux/), which looks like exactly what you're looking for.

Also, Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings should restart your iPhone.