# How to turn off iPhone without power button?

Tags: iphone, repair

My iPhone's power button is broken. How can I still turn it off to send it in for repairs? I found another [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5222/how-can-i-reset-my-iphone-1-without-using-the-broken-power-button), but it does not really help.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you go to Settings>General>Accessibility>AssistiveTouch and flip the switch to "on," you will find a black square with a white dot in the middle.

When you tap the white circle for AssistiveTouch, tap "Device," then LONG PRESS on the "Lock Screen" option.  You should be set!

Comment: Very good workaround! This works for me!

Comment: I had this switched on but never tried the long press! Awesome!

Comment: related: To turn it back on, plug in the computer cable.